# Angular 9 / SCSS not applied only for a child of a custom tag

Tags: sass, angular9

I´m trying to work on my own angular library which was compatible for Angular 4.
My goal is to make it compatible for Angular 9.
For some reason, css is not applied for a child of a component. This component is the last nested component.

**HTML output**

```
<ui-label _ngcontent-nln-c13="" _nghost-nln-c12="" ng-reflect-label="test">
    <span _ngcontent-nln-c12="">test</span>
</ui-label>
```

**label.component.scss**

```
foo-label {
  //font-style: italic; //<-- works here :/
  > span{
    font-style: italic; //<-- not applied
  }
}
```

Someone has got an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it´s not applied.
It´s due to a scope component.

`foo-label` was wrapped by `foo-tag` like this :

```
<foo-tag _ngcontent-han-c14="" _nghost-han-c13="" ng-reflect-label="test" ng-reflect-hlevel="1">
    <h1 _ngcontent-han-c13="">
        <foo-label _ngcontent-han-c13="" _nghost-han-c12="" ng-reflect-label="test">
             <span _ngcontent-han-c12="">test</span>
        </foo-label>
    </h1>
</foo-tag>
```

And the style was written in `tag.component.scss`.
like this :

**tag.component.scss**

```
:host{
    > h1 {
        > foo-label { //<--applied css until here !
           > span {
             ...
           }
        }
    }
}
```

You can fix with `::ng-deep` like this :

```
:host{
    > h1 {
        ::ng-deep > foo-label {
           > span {
             ...
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Works with mixin as well like this :

```
:host{
    > h1 {
        @include h($light-color, $title-header-size, $application-toolbar-icon-size);
    }
}

@mixin h($text-color, $font-size, $size-img){
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    ::ng-deep > foo-label {
        @include label($text-color, $font-size, $size-img);
    }
}
```